# Request is returning an IRI instead of an object in a nested relationship

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

Let say I have two entities : Book and Author, which are set up like this :

Author.php

```
/**
* @ApiResource(attributes={
*     "normalization_context"={"groups"={"author"}, "enable_max_depth"=true},
*     "denormalization_context"={"groups"={"author"}, "enable_max_depth"=true}
* })
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\AuthorRepository")
*/
class Author
{
...
/**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Book", mappedBy="author", orphanRemoval=true)
    * @Groups({"author", "book"})
    * @MaxDepth(3)
    */
    private $books;
```

Book.php

```
/**
* @ApiResource(attributes={
*     "normalization_context"={"groups"={"book"}, "enable_max_depth"=true},
*     "denormalization_context"={"groups"={"book"}, "enable_max_depth"=true}
* })
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\BookRepository")
*/
class Book
{
...
/**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Author", inversedBy="books")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
    * @Groups({"book", "author"})
    * @MaxDepth(3)
    */
    private $author;
```

I want to get a book with his author, and all the books this author has written. This way I can later iterate over this collection of books.

The problem is when I request the url :

```
GET localhost:8001/api/books/1
```

The response is as follow :

```
{
    "@context": "/api/contexts/Book",
    "@id": "/api/books/1",
    "@type": "Book",
    "author": {
        "@id": "/api/authors/1",
        "@type": "Author",
        "books": [
            "/api/books/1",
            {
                "@id": "/api/books/2",
                "@type": "Book",
                "author": "/api/authors/1"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I would like to get the book 1 as an objet, not as an IRI, what did I mess up ?

edit : to clarify, the response I am expecting is :

```
{
    "@context": "/api/contexts/Book",
    "@id": "/api/books/1",
    "@type": "Book",
    "author": {
        "@id": "/api/authors/1",
        "@type": "Author",
        "books": [
            {
                "@id": "/api/books/1",
                "@type": "Book",
                "author": "/api/authors/1"
            },
            {
                "@id": "/api/books/2",
                "@type": "Book",
                "author": "/api/authors/1"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

edit : [link to test repo](https://github.com/BPagoaga/POC-MaxDepth)

Comment: Well, given that you're on `/api/books/1` already, it kinda makes sense to not show nested "self". I guess this is the serializer way to prevent any circular reference issue. Maybe playing with max depth would help?

Comment: Playing with max depth does not help, but I guess I should play with either setCircularReferenceLimit or setCircularReferenceHandler to avoid this. Still trying to figure out how to do this.

Comment: Try adding "book" to the normalization_context of your Author class and the fields you want to display. https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization#embedding-relations

Comment: Well, if you ever figure it out, i'd be interested in an explanation ^^ Good luck!

Comment: @Bernard Pagoaga Were you able to solve the issue ?

Comment: Clearing the cache did help for me `php bin/console cache:clear`